# catching GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ConnectException and showing a custom message

Tags: php, laravel

I couldn't get a work around to catch this error and showing a custom message to user,
I tried to use web3js with laravel
https://github.com/IlyasDeckers/web3php

and when I tried to use this

```
      $eth = new \IlyasDeckers\Web3PHP\Ethereum(env('WEB3_URL'), env('WEB3_PORT'));
     try {
        $eth = $eth->eth_getBalance('0x8fbb99e9e73cd62bb3adea5365ff0f9d90c9e532', $block='latest', $decode_hex=false);
    }

    catch(ConnectException $e) {
    echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
    exit;
   }
```

I am getting the error which cannot be caught, can anyone help on this?

> GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ConnectException cURL error 7: Failed to
>   connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8545: Connection refused (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds very much to me like you aren't running an Ethereum node. It's trying to connect to localhost on port 8545.

If you are running a node, check the port!

If you aren't running a node, either set one up, or find one that will allow you to connect (far less likely tbh).

**UPDATE**

I notice you are catching a ConnectException, the fully qualified classname being `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException`.

If you haven't imported the class name using a use statement, then you need to change your code to this:

```
catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException) {
```

(note the leading backslash). However, this isn't the recommended way. It's better to import all your classes at the top of your script:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException;
```

That way, you can instantly see all classes used in the script, and you can refer to the class as just `ConnectException` throughout your code.

Comment: yes, I need to warn the users for the same with a message.

Comment: put that first line in the try block, the exception is being thrown from there

Comment: actually, it is the next line, when I have just the first line it doesn't do much than initialization 

      $eth = new \IlyasDeckers\Web3PHP\Ethereum(env('WEB3_URL'), env('WEB3_PORT'));
        print_r(  $eth);exit;

//IlyasDeckers\Web3PHP\Ethereum Object ( [host:protected] => 127.0.0.1 [port:protected] => 8545 [version:protected] => 2.0 [id:protected] => 0 )

Comment: Do you have  `use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException;` at the top of your script? If not it won't be caught.

Comment: wow :) it's a shame I didn't know that even after years of experience in PHP, thanks so much, can you add it to your answer?, so I can accept and it may be useful for someone in future..